# Can I Expense Reimbursements To An Employee Who Received Medical Treatment In A Foreign Country?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, small-business, medical-bill

I have an employee who was sent to a foreign country on a business trip.  He got in an accident while he was there and had to be treated at a hospital.  Since he was there on a company trip, we reimbursed him for his out of pocket.

Can this be expensed on our tax return?  If so, under what category?